# Meaning and syntactic function of modal verb.

Tags: modal-verbs, discourse-context

> He **would be** a servant in his family.

In what sense is the construction (**would be**) used?

It's a modal verb right? And as it's a predicate in this sentence,what type of predicate is it?

Comment: More context is required.

Comment: I'm afraid it's all we have.

Comment: In that case there's not enough to give an answer. Voting to close.

Comment: Can there be at least any suggestions?

Comment: The suggestion would be to read the answers to similar questions on the use of 'would be', which have been asked here many times.  It's either an unhappy condition or a fervent wish.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Do you know what your cited sentence is intended to *mean*? If so, tell us. Do you want to know the technical terminology relevant to the construction? If so, within what *framework*?

Comment: I want to know if "would be" is expressing assumption or repetition of an action or anything else. Then I want to know if it is a verbal or verbal aspective predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER:
We really and truly can't answer these questions.

LONGER ANSWER:

**1. In what sense is the construction *would be* used?**

*Would* may have many different meanings.

- It may represent the simple past form of *will* with futurive sense, marking what follows as an eventuality occurring after the ‘Reference Time’ of the surrounding discourse:

  > John came to the Fitzwilliams in 1274 and would be a servant in his family until he married Margaret in 1286.
- It may represent the simple past form of *will* with repetitive sense, marking what follows as habitual or (if emphasized) perverse activity at the past RT:

  > John would be a servant in his family whenever illustrious visitors were entertained, but was treated otherwise as a member of the family.
  >   John **would** be a servant in his family, even when they wanted him to lead.
- In the apodosis (consequence clause) of a conditional construction it may express the consequence of a hypothetical or counterfactual condition; this will support either a past or present RT:

  > If Mark had his way John would be a servant in his family.
- In the protasis (condition clause) of a conditional construction it may express consent (again with either past or present RT):

  > If John would be a servant in his family, Mark would treat him better.
- And in older English, or archaizing Present Day English, it may express desire (again with either past or present RT):

  > John would be a servant in his family, for he {is / was} a humble man.

Without further context it is impossible to know which meaning is intended here.

**2. What type of predicate is it?**

The English grammatical tradition does not categorize verbs (or the predicates in which they participate) by their semantic roles but by their syntactic roles. What we call ‘modal verbs’<sup>†</sup> are a distinct grammatical category; they are distinguished from other verbs in being used **only** as auxiliaries and in lacking certain morphological forms which other verbs present: they have no distinct 3sg  form and no participles. Moreover, their ‘plain’ form is never employed as an infinitive or imperative. These are called ‘modal’ verbs because all of their uses express (or must harmonize with) a marked modal meaning; but they are by no means the **only** English verbs which express such modality. In our grammatical tradition, however, ordinary ‘lexical’ verbs are never called modals, whatever their meaning. *Want*, for instance, although it expresses bouletic modality, is not categorized as a ‘modal’ but as a ‘catenating’ and ‘raising-to-object’ verb: terms which distinguish the sorts of syntactic relationships they enter into.

(*Similarly, in the English grammatical tradition verbs and verbal constructions which express aspect or Aktionsart are not ordinarily sorted into a distinct category. In fact, aside from some very awkward 18th- and 19th-century attempts to apply terms from Latin and Greek grammar (‘imperfect’, ‘aorist’), aspect and Aktionsart were little understood among English grammarians until Slavic linguists taught us about them in the early 20th century. To this day aspect is basically ignored in primary and secondary education, and even in universities outside of linguistics classes.*)

In the same way, the English grammatical tradition simply does not employ the predicate taxonomy your question assumes; and I am puzzled to see what the taxonomy would reveal about how utterances in my language are put together. I have no knowledge of Russian at all; but I suspect that the taxonomy is useful in Russian because categories like *aspective compound verbal predicate* govern what morphologies are employed. This is not the case in English, where morphology plays only a very small role in syntax and what sorts of complements are employed is a property of individual verbs.

<sup>†</sup>  <sub>There are five (or nine, if you count the present/past forms as distinct lexemes) “core” *modal verbs*: *can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would*, and a handful of *semi-modals* which sometimes behave like the core modals. In addition, there are idioms such as *have to* and *be going to* and *be able * which may replace core modals; these are sometimes called *periphrastic modals*.</sub>